# Consecutive chat messages from deleted users don't show up combined, as they normally do for non-deleted users

Tags: bug, chat, deleted-accounts

When a user posts multiple consecutive chat messages during a short period of time, and there are no messages from others in between, those messages are combined into a single "list item" in chat rooms and transcripts. This works if the posting user's chat profile isn't deleted.

However, the same doesn't happen if the user who posted the chat messages later has their chat profile deleted. The messages show as separate list items, even though they were posted consecutively and would show combined had the user's chat profile not been deleted.

[image: Chat messages not merged]

(Don't try exploiting the "bug" mentioned in the above chat messages - that was fixed four years later, after I brought it up in chat again.)